# Изменить стрелки во Vue3-carousel

Tags: vue3

```
<carousel :items-to-show="4">
    <slide v-for="(item, index) in listPop" :key="index">
      {{ item.name }}
    </slide>

    <template #addons>
      <navigation/>
      
    </template>
  </carousel>
```

Вот код. Можно ли  сделать кастомные стрелки чтоб работали
Помогите пожалуйста

Дополнение
Я использую Vue3 и на данный момент нужно сделать слайдер Нашёл компонент который поможет и он работает с Vue3 Но есть проблема. В том что я не могу изменить стандартные стрелки для навигации

Comment: Можно чуть больше уточнения в вопросе?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я использую Vue3 и на данный момент нужно сделать слайдер
Нашёл компонент который поможет и он работает с Vue3
Но есть проблема. В том что я не могу изменить стандартные стрелки для навигации

Comment: @ТомашЕглиш: Вас попросили добавить больше подробностей в вопрос, а не скопировать из вопроса в комментарий. Что непонятного в просьбе?

Comment: (карусели разные конечно),  но В браузере - F-12 - откройте Elements - сверху угловой стрелка - нажмите - выберите на странице нужный вам элемент - посмотрите его CLASS (или несколько последовательных классов) - и переопределите его в своем CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему
Заменить с помощью JS весь HTML который отвечает за отображение)
Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вам стоит попробовать поменять стили на кнопкам. Например, задать фоновую картинку с помощью base64

```
 background-image: 'data:image/png; base64, ...';
```